# How to use ClipBoard on windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to copy a phonenumber from PeopleHub, and then paste it to my app, is there have a ClipBoard API to support do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only set text to clipboard in windows phone and can not read:

```
System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText( TextBox.Text );
```

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)